# How to draw cleverly a complex shape in Android

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

I'm working on a university project in which I need to visualize on a smartphone datas from pressure sensors built in an insole.
I need to draw on a `View`, as a background, a footprint, something like the image below but just for one foot. [image]

I don't want to use a static image because with different screens resolution it could lose too much quality, so I'm trying to do it by code.
The main problem is that I'm not very skilled in graphic programming so I have not a smart approach to this problem.

The first and only idea that I had was to take the insole's CAD representation, with its real dimensions, scale it in function of screen's ones and put it together using simple shapes (arc, circle, ecc...) available in Android.
In this way I'm creating a `Path` which will compose the whole footprint, once I will draw it with a `Canvas`.

This method will let me to do the work but is awful and needs an exceptional amount of work and time to set every part.
I have searched for some similar questions but I haven't found anything to solve my problem.

Is there (of course there is) a smarter way to do this stuff, saving time and energies?

Thank you

Comment: Android has a support for .SVG (scallable vector graphics) files. Maybe try drawing the insoles in some free editor (googling somehting like "svg editor"), download the file, add it to the project and then just invoke .setBackgroundResource(..) on your View with the ID of your .SVG insole image resource.

Answer (score 0):

**of course, you can always use open gl es**

this method might not save your time and energy but will give you a better graphic and scope to improve it for later purpose

the concept is to create a float buffer with all the points of your footwear and then draw is with connected lines on a `surfaceView`

to get started with open gl es you can use this tutorial : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

and here is an example : https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: I need to approximate the footwear with a series of points (eg. 100) and then connect them with a line. If i've understood in this way i have only to retrieve a pair of coordinates for each point. Is it correct?

Comment: well yes.. a line (lets say a open gl es line) requires 2 points to draw a line and each point has 2 axis(x and y). and you don't have to do it accurately for every point on the figure..for example if the figure already has string line shapes in certain parts you can easily make those parts and for curves there are way to draw a circle or any arc with just lines...search for those..